# How to scrape a web page with supplimentary information with python?

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I am trying to use a public data from WTO.

https://rtais.wto.org/UI/PublicAllRTAList.aspx

The above web page shows all the regional trade agreements(RTA). However, it doesn't show the list of countries in each RTA. I am doing this by hand, checking each agreement and attach them into the dataframe in R, but I guess there must be a more efficient way to do this.

I am not familiar to Web scraping but I can use R and python in a basic sense.

Any recommendation or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it'd be easier if the links to the RTAs were actually links instead of js postbacks I would assume.

Comment: Does this mean, for instance, that for the Agadir Agreement you would want to list Egypt, Jordan, Morocco, and Tunisia as the current signatories, as indicated in the page https://rtais.wto.org/UI/PublicShowRTAIDCard.aspx?rtaid=583?

Comment: @Bill Bell. Yes, that is exactly what I want. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: What list of agreements are you using to make your hand compilation?

Comment: @BillBell I did for all the RTAs in the pages. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but where did the list come from? Was it this one: https://rtais.wto.org/UI/PublicAllRTAList.aspx?

Comment: @BillBell Yes, you are right.

Comment: Many of us would find this somewhat challenging. Suggest using Python with selenium and PhantomJS. Split the agreement names in the lefthand column on the hyphens. Use lists of constants in your scripts to distinguish between organisation names such as 'EU' and country names such as 'Turkey'. It might help to run a preliminary script that fetches the pages for the organisation names first and gathers the list of participating countries, again using selenium. This would involve manual work (but less of it) identifying organisation names.